# Web Analytics Reports for a site in 2007 mode after a farm upgrade

Tags: 2010, 2007, upgrade, web-analytics

We did upgrade our SharePoint farm from 2007 to 2010 but we still have some sites that are still in 2007 mode. Because of this, the web analytics reports feature is not available but we noticed something interesting;

For a site that is still in 2007 mode, if we do visual upgrade for it or update its UI version, the Web Analytics Reports feature is coming because of the upgrade and we found that Web Analytics feature working properly (i.e. reports show all the available data since farm upgrade to 2010). When we revert back the upgrade, web analytics feature will be not available.

So my question is, if web analytics data are available somewhere if we do the UI upgrade to version 4, can we get that data in any way without doing any actual upgrade (i.e. we neek to keep these sites in 2007 mode)?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, Web Analytics reports are only available after (visual)upgrade. If you want those reports, you'll have to do the upgrade.